# Flickr integration in iOS app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an issue while integrating flickr in iOS app.
When I click on authorize button then it shows alert message as safari cannot open webpage because the address is invalid.
If anyone knows then please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the code that runs when you use the 'authorize button'?

Comment: authorize button(OK I'LL AUTHORIZE IT) is the button which comes after validating our yahoo credentials.

Comment: Do you mean a HTML button?  (Sorry, I'm still trying to figure out how this is an 'objective-c' question.)

Answer (score 3):

My best guess is you are missing URL SCHEME in your project plist. Below is the screenshot showing current sample from flickr sdk which I downloaded from github and there is a setup done for URL Scheme handling.

Its called oAuth handling when SAFARI is finished verifying the credentials and want to return to the application it returns URL which can be handled by the application mentioned in plist and which we will handle from application delegate using following function
So you need to provide your URL identifier and URL Scheme for your project which you can get if you register in flickr api.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
}
```

[image]